# Golang Decoding/Unmarshaling invalid unicode in JSON

Tags: json, unicode, go

I am fetching JSON files in go that are not formatted homogeneously.
For Example, I can have the following:

```
{"email": "\"blah.blah@blah.com\""}
{"email": "robert@gmail.com"}
{"name": "m\303\203ead"}
```

We can see that there will be a problem with the escaping character.
Using `json.Decode`:

With:

```
{"name": "m\303\203ead"}
```

I get the error: `invalid character '3' in string escape code`

I have tried several approaches to normalise my data for example by passing by a string array (it works but there is too many edge cases), or even to filter escape characters.

Finally, I came through this article: (http://blog.golang.org/normalization)
And the solution they proposed seemed very interesting.

I have tried the following

```
isMn := func(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.Is(unicode.Mn, r)
}

t := transform.Chain(norm.NFC, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFD)

fileReader, err := bucket.GetReader(filename)

transformReader := transform.NewReader(fileReader, t)

decoder := json.NewDecoder(tReader)

for {
    var dataModel Model
    if err := decoder.Decode(&kmData); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else {
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

With `Model` being:

```
type Model struct {
    Name  string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email" bson:"email"` 
}
```

I have tried several variations of it, but haven't been able to have it working.

So my question is how to easily handle decoding/unmarshaling JSON data with different encodings? Knowing, that I have no control on those JSON files.

If you are reading this, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `json.RawMessage` instead of `string`, that way `json.Decode` won't try to decode the invalid characters.

playground : http://play.golang.org/p/fB-38KGAO0

```
type Model struct {
    N  json.RawMessage `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}

func (m *Model) Name() string {
    return string(m.N)
}
func main() {
    s := "{\"name\": \"m\303\203ead\"}"
    r := strings.NewReader(s)
    d := json.NewDecoder(r)
    m := Model{}

    fmt.Println(d.Decode(&m))
    fmt.Println(m.Name())
}
```

Edit: Well, you can use regex, not sure how viable that is for you http://play.golang.org/p/VYJKTKmiYm:

```
func cleanUp(s string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\b(\\\d\d\d)`)
    return re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(s, func(s string) string {
        return `\u0` + s[1:]
    })
}
func main() {
    s := "{\"name\": \"m\303\203ead\"}"
    s = cleanUp(s)
    r := strings.NewReader(s)
    d := json.NewDecoder(r)
    m := Model{}
    fmt.Println(d.Decode(&m))
    fmt.Println(m.Name())
}
```

Comment: Really nice. +1. I will no doubt use this also.

Comment: Awesome solution. If does indeed fix that case, it still doesn't fix the cases when the data encoding is wrong like [here](http://play.golang.org/p/xaFCJfBMl1) . I'm very tempted to replace every `\` to nil but it is quite risky...

Comment: I can't really thing of anything right now, gotta pre-process the json text before parsing it.

Comment: Yeap it worked thank you! But I ended up transforming it to strings before to decode the JSONs